# Need to know mysqli_connect default time out

Tags: php, mysql, linux, mysqli

I have a application on Linux platform and want to change mysql to mysqli(improved) and  want confirm the default time out of mysqli_connect()

In real i want to use persistent connection in mysqli

Comment: Typically 30 seconds. Check you php.ini file. Also depends on browser and apache timeouts assuming you arent running via cli.

Answer (score 0):

As per this page : http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.mysql.announce/631

> - On Windows, the default value for the
>           MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT option to mysql_options() is no
>           longer 20 seconds. Now the default is no timeout
>           (infinite), the same as on other platforms.

The answer seems to be "no timeout" as a default on all platforms.

Comment: I want to know at linux system

Comment: @MianAnjum why don't you just set it then?

Comment: As my answer tells you : the default is "no timeout" on ALL PLATFORMS :)

Comment: @MianAnjum go on, use it. What is your question?